# Adding magento cart to existing website

Tags: magento, e-commerce, shopping-cart

I am very much eager if any one knows is it possible to add magento to an existing website, I want my website look the same.The website consists may use customers to buy domains by clicking ADD button/links for adding into shopping cart, but as of now there is no shopping cart functionality. Is this Possible? If yes, is there any code or documentation to follow the steps to integrate.Any help is appreciated, thanks in Advance.

Comment: I have few questions for you,
Do you have to carry out the user session?
May I know the purpose or reason for integrating both sites?

Comment: yes we need to carry out the user session and also the cart and check out process from the magento to the normal site

Comment: Purpose of integrating both the sites?